# how to show different attribute after some time period from XML in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, yahoo-api

I am developing a windows forms application C# that will display the title of the news. So far, I can show only the 1st title. I want my app to show the next title after 20 second and so on. If I run out of titles, it will go back to the top again. so far I have done this:

```
private void GetNewsTopStories()
{
    string queryNews = String.Format("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/");
    XmlDocument wData = new XmlDocument();
    wData.Load(queryNews);

    XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(wData.NameTable);

    XmlNode channel = wData.SelectSingleNode("rss").SelectSingleNode("channel");
    XmlNodeList nodes = wData.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item", manager);

    titleNews = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText;
    topNewsLabel.Text = titleNews.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string URL = "http://news.yahoo.com/rss/";
        string[] titles = null;
        int count = -1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        }

        private void buttonEnd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 20000;
            count = -1;
            timer1.Enabled = true;

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((count == -1) || (count >= titles.Count()))
            {
                GetFeeds();
                count = 0;
            }
            textBox1.Text = titles[count++];

        }
        public void GetFeeds()
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);
            titles = doc.Descendants("item").Select(x => (string)x.Element("title")).ToArray();
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }


}
```